# Apple Notes - using different Passwords for locking and unlocking

Tags: macos, notes.app

I have a long-standing password for locking notes in the macOS Notes app. Today I attempted to lock a new note and I got an error message telling me that my Notes password is incorrect.

I tried it multiple times and got the same error.

I'm certain I have the password right. I tried using the same password to unlock existing notes and they unlock without problem. If I try to lock the new note, it says the password is incorrect.

Finally, I wrote out the password in plain text to check that it is correct, then copied it. I pasted it to unlock an existing note with success. When pasting the password to lock the new note, it says the password is incorrect.

Any ideas? Is this a bug? I'm on macOS 10.14.6

It may or may not be relevant but I also noticed today that when I unlocked existing notes it only unlocked the one I chose and I had to unlock each individually. I could have sworn when I unlock one note it unlocks all the other ones with the same password.

## Update

I restarted and the problem persisted. After resetting the password new notes can now lock successfully. I hadn't ever used the reset or change password dialog up until this point.

I'm slightly bothered by this behavior because of the potential to lock me out of notes I created and the tiny concern that the password has been compromised. I've no other reason to think it has other than my Notes window losing focus every few minutes or so. I think it coincides with the *uploading* symbol in the corner as the notes sync to iCloud. But it can lose my place when I'm typing and seems like an unnecessary flaw.

Comment: @IconDaemon I appreciate the editing to make the post more readable, thanks - I wrote it in such a rush and should have waited. However some of the edits introduced some cumbersome grammar of their own (repeating 'then' in adjoining sentences) and changed the tone of some sentences beyond a simple correction (adding exclamation marks etc) that I would not have used. No big deal, I'm not going to change it back.

Comment: I will re-edit my edits. :-)

Comment: Just thought it was worth pointing out if you're going to the trouble of helping out with improving the readability of posts. Thanks again.

Comment: stopping by to say I am experiencing this exact issue right now.  Chatting with apple support.  I can unlock all my locked notes, and I would never even consider changing my notes password....  I also seem to remember that unlocking one note unlocked them all (historically)

Comment: any chance you recently sold an old Mac?

Comment: @goofology That's a good suggestion but, no, I hadn't.